# How do I know when a JMenuItem is shown? Adding a ComponentListener and using componentShown doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

Below is a complete compiling running failing example illustrating my question. JMenuItem extends JComponent. When added to JPopupMenu and shown in a context menu... it is... well... *SHOWN*, but the `componentShown` method is *not* called. How can I know when the JMenuItem is shown? I need to know from within the JMenuItem itself. I'm creating this JMenuItem and handing it off to a larger framework. I have no knowledge or control of the JPopupMenu, container, or any other components. When my JMenuItem is shown, I must update its text based on the context and current state of the app. How do I know when it is shown?

In the following example, the text "component shown" is never printed under any circumstances. Right click inside the JPanel to get the context menu and you'll see the JMenuItem text, "Reply Hi", but now output to the console.

I'm running on macOS 11.5.2 Big Sur and JDK 11.0.6 LTS (from Oracle).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JMenuItemListeners {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello World... right click me."),
                BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //========================================
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Reply Hi");
        menuItem.addComponentListener(
        new ComponentListener() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("component shown");
            }
            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
        }
                );
        popupMenu.add(menuItem);
        panel.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
        //========================================
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `AncestorListener`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JMenuItemListeners {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello World... right click me."),
                BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //========================================
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Reply Hi");

        menuItem.addAncestorListener(new AncestorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent e) {
                System.out.println("ancestor shown");
            }
        });

        popupMenu.add(menuItem);
        panel.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
        //========================================
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That only works the first time the `JPopupMenu` is shown. The second time the menu is shown the event is not fired.

Comment: @Jason Works fine for me using JDK11 on Windows 10. The normal solution would be to add a `PopupMenuListener` to the `JPopupMenu` to be notify when the popup is about to be displayed. You stated in your question that you don't have access to the popup menu. Well if this only displays once for you it will give you access to the popup menu and you can add the listener to the popup at this time to handle whatever it is you want to do. Unless you can post a realistic [mre] of what you are attempting this is the best we can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you'll find some kind of listener that is notified when a `JMenuItem` is shown.

I would instead try to decouple the `JMenuItem` from the state of your application and I would do that using a `javax.swing.AbstractAction`.

You can update the `AbstractAction` anytime the context and / or state of your application changes and magically when the `JMenuItem` is shown it will reflect the context and state of your application.

The code fragment below contains replaces the creation of the `JPopupMenu` and the `JMenuItem`. The second part shows how you would update the `AbstractAction` by turning the `JMenuItem` into a clock.

```
    //========================================
    JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    AbstractAction a = new AbstractAction("Reply Hi") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
    };
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(a);
    popupMenu.add(menuItem);
    panel.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
    //========================================
    Timer t = new Timer(100, (e) -> {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Its 'HH:mm:ss");
        a.putValue(Action.NAME, dtf.format(LocalTime.now()));
    });
    t.start();
    //========================================
```

Comment: There's really no difference between this and just calling `JMenuItem.setText(String)`. I would not call this "decoupled". Instead, it's an extra layer of complexity. Wherever I put this abstract action, I could just put the JMenuItem. Wherever I call `putValue`, I could call `setText`. And in fact, my solution is exactly that. I keep track of the `JMenuItem` instance and call `setText` on it in the appropriate place.

Comment: I did give this solution a sincere try. I put it in my code and played with it. I appreciate the effort, really. I spent about 30 minutes toying around with it before I concluded this was just a more complex version of what I was already doing that added no value. I'm really looking for something more React like... FRP - Functional Reactive Programing... where the view is a function of the state, not "the state is pushed to the view". It makes sense to have the view update itself from the state when it's shown. Too bad not all components know when they are shown!!

Comment: Which is CRAZY given they ALL have a `componentShown` method.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is for the `JPopupMenu` to listen to the `popupMenuWillBecomeVisible` event in the `PopupMenuListener`. It is called whenever the popup is about to be displayed to the user. Within that method you can make any updates to your `JMenuItem` such as: checked-state, caption, icon, enabled, visible, tooltip, etc.

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu; //This is optional
JPopupMenu popupMenu = menu.getPopupMenu(); //Obtain the popup menu however you need to
popupMenu.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {
    //Called anytime the popup is about to be displayed
    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        menuItem.setSelected(isSelected());
        menuItem.setText(getMenuText());
        menuItem.setIcon(getMenuIcon());
        menuItem.setEnabled(isMenuEnabled());
        menuItem.setToolTipText(getTooltipText());
        menuItem.setVisible(isMenuVisible());
    }
    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) { }
    @Override
    public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) { }
});
```